# How do I convert timespan method to decimal?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
TimeSpan span1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(dtmIn.Value.Hour);
TimeSpan span2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(dtmOut.Value.Hour);
TimeSpan span3 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dtmIn.Value.Minute);
TimeSpan span4 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dtmOut.Value.Minute);
TimeSpan span5 = span2.Subtract(span1) + span4.Subtract(span3);

lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(span5).ToString("#.00");
```

I get a formatting error for the last line. I can get the label to return as time obviously, but I need it to return as a decimal.

Comment: A decimal representing what? Seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: Yes fractions of an hour. I am basically trying to figure out the pay of an employee. I was wondering how to convert to decimal form than multiply by an hourly rate and return as currency in the label.

Comment: Ah, then try to be more specific next time. For your case, I would use something like: decimal amount = Math.Round(span5.TotalHours * rate, 2); Then print it out with what ever formatting you want, such as String.Format("{0:C}", amount);

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to convert a `TimeSpan` to a decimal, becuase time isn't numeric.

You probably want `span5.TotalHours`, which is a `double` that includes the fractional portion.

Comment: Well, I want to convert to a decimal and multiply by a number. I am trying to calculate pay based on hours in decimal form then multiply by hourly rate. Understand?

Comment: Then you want `TotalHours`, as I suspected.

Comment: Alright, then what would be appropriate to multiply by 3 and return the label as Currency?

Comment: Are you asking me how to multiply a number by `3`?

Comment: How would I multiply the result by 3 and return as currency in the label?

Answer (score 1):

What is the decimal supposed to represent? Hours and fractions of an hour? You must understand that `TimeSpan` can't infer this, as `TimeSpan` could span milliseconds or millennia.

If in fact hours and fractions of an hour, then:

```
lbTotal.Text = span5.TotalHours.ToString("#.00");
```